# How to apply both TextStyle and textTheme to a Text widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-text

For a Text like:

```dart
Text(
   'Hello World',
   style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
    )
```

Is there a way to merge textTheme with a TextStyle? Like say, to modify the color of the text..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do something like

```dart
Theme.of(context)
.textTheme.display1
.merge(TextStyle(color: Colors.red)
```

and apply it to the style

Answer (score 1):

Merge method causes error in Flutter 2.2 because of the null safety feature.
Don't forget to add "?" after the variable.

```
Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1?.merge(TextStyle(color: Colors.red)
```